# Java regex for String:number:String?

Tags: java, regex

Hi i want to know about a regex for parsing

```
InputDispatcherTest.TimmyTest_ASSERT
customize/base/services/input/tests/InputDispatcher_test.cpp:153: Failure
```

i am using `\\s[:]\\d[:]\\s` but it's not working.

Comment: i have even tried \\S but result is same.

Comment: What would be wrong with `.*:\\d+:.*`? Anyway, you are clearly missing `+` after your `\\d`.

Comment: @AshwaniKumar Note that `\\S` matches non space characters, `\\s` matches spaces.

Comment: ... and it matches **only a single character** if not followed by * or +.

Comment: *what* are you trying to parse? is this java or c++?

Comment: I am working with log files... reading them line by line and then working on the string values.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of number?  Integer?  Floating point?  What's your input?

That doesn't look right to me.  I'd do this for integers:

```
^\\d+$
```

I'd recommend trimming the String before you check.

Comment: You need "it's" == "it is".  Trim it first and use my recommendation.  It'll work better.

Answer (score 1):

\s matches a whitespace character, Try:

```
\\w+[:]\\d+[:]\\w+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would suffice :

```
".+:\\d+:.+"
```

Answer (score 0):

"\S+[.]\S+:\d+:[ ]\S+"

I used above Regex as a solution